# C++: " multiple definition of 'mainCRTStartup' " error etc

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So I was doing some beginner challenges and wanted to modify my code, this was what i did first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random;
int guess;
int num_guess = 1;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    random = rand() % 100 + 1;

    std::cout << "Try to guess my number between 1 and 100." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> guess;

    while(guess > random){
        std::cout << "Sorry too high but i'll give you another try." <<     std::endl;
        std::cin >> guess;
        num_guess += 1;
    }

    while(guess < random){
        std::cout << "Sorry too low but i'll give you another try." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> guess;
        num_guess += 1;
    }

    if(guess = random){
        std::cout << "WOW! Congratulations you actually got it, you did use " << num_guess << " tries tho." << std::endl;
    }


    return(0);
}
```

It is supposed to generate a random number between 1 and 100, and then you guess what number it is. But then I copied this code over to another file under the same project because im doing this in school so I wanted all the different versions of my code for documentary purposes. But when I started writing the new code where the program is supposed to guess a number you give it between 1 and 100.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int number;
int guess = 100;
int num_guess = 1;

int main(){
    std::cout << "Please enter any number between 1 and 100" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number;
    if(number > 100 && number < 1){
        std::cout << "Enter a valid number" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> number;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    guess = rand() % guess + 1;


    return(0);
}
```

I erased the old code from main.cpp and wrote this instead, but when I tried to run it i got these error messages:

- multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
- multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
- multiple definition of `atexit'
- multiple definition of `_onexit'
- multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
- multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
- undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'|

Comment: You defined several `main` functions. How linker must find an entry point?

Comment: If the files belong to the same project, the compiler will try to include both of them in the same executable. And then there will be two `main()` functions, apparently dragging in two of everything. So just create a new project.

Comment: Not caused by having multiple main() functions.  You are linking the C runtime library more than once.  No breadcrumbs in the question to guess how that could have happened.  Creating a new project instead of trying to re-use an old one would be the most obvious alternative to get ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you didn't exclude your old file from the project. In this case linker meets two `main` functions and doesn't know what to use. Possible ways to solve it:

1. exclude unused file from the project;
2. comment out old version;
3. use conditional compilation:

   ```
    #ifdef OLD_VER
    // main1
    ...
    #else
    // main2
    ...
    #endif
   ```
4. create a new project;
5. use version control systems.

First 3 methods are not recommended for a long use. The last one is a good point (the best point, I think) but it can require elementary VCSs learning.